# Unable to redirect http://localhost/api/api_authenticate.php to http://localhost/api/authenticate

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm experiencing an issue with configuring my .htaccess file for URL rewriting. Here is my complete .htaccess file:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^login\.php$ /login [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^logout\.php$ /logout [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^admin/user/([0-9]+)$ admin/user.php?id=$1 [L]

# The following rule is not working
RewriteRule ^api/api_authenticate\.php$ /api/authenticate [L,R=301]
```

I'm unable to rewrite the URL from http://localhost/api/api_authenticate.php to http://localhost/api/authenticate (404 error). However, I can still access http://localhost/api/api_authenticate.php directly.
Other rule work fine.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Does the rewrite not happen, or are you getting the 404 _for_ `/api/authenticate`?

Comment: Might be the effect of `MultiViews` once again, try and disable that.

Comment: I'm getting `404 Not Found` when I try to access http://localhost/api/authenticate but if i try to access for example http://localhost/admin/user/90 it's working fine

Comment: Despite adding `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes` to the beginning of my .htaccess file, the issue still persists.

Comment: _"but if i try to access for example localhost/admin/user/90 it's working fine"_ - that one you are rewriting to a script file. But what in your setup is supposed to handle the request URL `/api/authenticate`?

Comment: For `/api/authenticate`, I'm also pointing to a script file located at `C:\wamp64\www\api\api_authenticate.php`

Comment: And where exactly does that happen?

Comment: Well, I want to point the file `C:\wamp64\www\api\api_authenticate.php` to `/api/authenticate` using the .htaccess

Comment: Rather the other way around - you want to map the incoming request for `/api/authenticate`, to your script file. And _did_ you actually do that, or are you still at the "wanting" stage?

Comment: I'm in the wanting stage, sorry for the confusion

Comment: So implement something similar to what you already have for the `admin/user/...` route.

Comment: I also tried using `RewriteRule ^api/authenticate$ api/api_authenticate.php [L]` but still not working :/

Comment: "Not working" meaning what, exactly? Still a 404? Which URL are you requesting?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting a 404 error.  I'm requesting http://localhost/api/authenticate

Comment: Do you still have the rule in there, that is supposed to perform the redirect in the "other direction"? If so, comment that out for now, to make sure it doesn't interfere.

Comment: I have only one .htaccess file, the full content is in the question. I tried the rule one by one and removing the old one for `/api/authenticate`

Comment: _"the full content is in the question"_ - but it has been modified since ... Seeing what you _actually_ have right now, would be more helpful, than vague verbal explanations of what was changed. But if you really just replaced the last rule with the new one, I don't see why this should not be working. You can always enable some rewrite logging, that helps to figure out what exactly is going on.

Comment: I updated the content of .htaccess in the question.